# Sencha touch on chrome OS

Tags: sencha-touch-2, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have developed an application by Sencha touch ,it works properly,but in Chrome OS it loads phone view instead of table one ,what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same thing.  Unfortunately Chrome OS's user agent isn't recognised by Sencha Touch as a tablet.  But you can change the `isActive` function in your Tablet.js profile to recognise Chrome by it's UserAgent.

Hope this bit of code helps:

Tablet.js:

```
isActive : function() {
    return Ext.os.is.Tablet || Ext.browser.userAgent.indexOf('CrOS') != -1;
}
```

This returns true if sencha recognises the browser to come from a Tablet or if the UserAgent contains the text "CrOS" (which Chrome OS does).